# Workaround a client identification by website

Tags: security, http, session

Which way a website can determine that opened on one computer in multiple copies simultaneously? How can I to cheat it?

Comment: Across multiple browsers? You can't. There are a variety of unreliable things you could try like limiting by IP address, but why? What “security” aim are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to open the site twice on the same computer that the site did not know about it.

Comment: Oh, it's an attacker question not defender! Well: start with opening the site from two different browsers, each with browsing history cleared, so they have no history or fingerprint the site can recognise. Disable plugins like Flash and Java that might offer more direct access to the machine. If they are going on IP address, set one browser up to use a proxy. Anything more than that is unusual and we'd have to look at the site to get an idea what was happening.